# Incompatible pointer types returning swift class from Obj-C function

Tags: swift, objective-c, return-type, swift-protocols

I have a swift protocol Fruit, a swift class Pear, and a method in an Objc-c file returning a pointer to Pear.

```
protocol Fruit: NSObjectProtocol {
}

@objcMembers
class Pear: NSObject, Fruit {
  init()
}
```

In an Obj-C file, I have

```
@protocol Fruit;

- (NSObject<Fruit> *)getFavoriteFruit {
  return [[Pear alloc] init]; // <- Error here
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Incompatible pointer types returning 'Pear *' from a function with result type 'NSObject<Fruit> * _Nonnull'

How are these different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two changes in your code.

One: Change the line:

```swift
protocol Fruit: NSObjectProtocol {
```

to:

```swift
@objc
protocol Fruit: NSObjectProtocol {
```

Two: Remove the line:

```objectivec
@protocol Fruit;
```

As your code is now, you are not using the Swift protocol in your Objective-C code. You are defining (via forward declaration) a different Objective-C protocol named `Fruit`. Since `Pear` conforms to the Swift `Fruit` protocol, your Objective-C code fails because the Swift `Pear` instance isn't an `NSObject` conforming to the different Objective-C `Fuit` protocol.

Comment: I had a feeling I was doing something weird interfacing between swift and Obj-C, thanks! Perfect explanation :)